# Access to Excel export updating specific field in Do While

Tags: excel, ms-access

I need to query a database table then write 3 of the 4 fields to an excel spreadsheet.  Once that line is written I need to update the 'sentback' field to 'Y'.  This was the initial field used in the where clause.  So the whole idea is to query, write, and change to flag to 'Y' so I do not select those records again.

I have half the code working here.  I know i can probably use the DoCmd somehow, but cant quite figure it out.

Other records could be added to the database during the running of the routine, so the update must happen on the current record set used in the do while in order to avoid setting the flag on records that may not have been sent.

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
Dim strSQL As String



strExcelFile = "C:\MySpreadSheet.xls"
strWorksheet = "WorkSheet1"
strDB = "C:\track.accdb"
strTable = "manifests2"

Set db = CurrentDb

'If excel file already exists, you can delete it here
If Dir(strExcelFile) <> "" Then Kill strExcelFile


strSQL = "SELECT manifests2.[Shipment ID], manifests2.[Courier Service Level],       manifests2.[Other Tracking],manifests2.[sentback]  FROM " & "[" & strTable & "] WHERE (((manifests2.[sentback]) = 'N') and ((manifests2.[Other Tracking]) <> NULL))"

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

Do While Not rs.EOF


    rs.Edit
    rs("sentback").Value = "Y"
    rs.Update

    rs.MoveNext
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Shipment ID is a unique identifier, which it seems to be, you can use the Excel file to update the table, thereby ensuring that only the records that are in the file are marked sent.

```
strExcelFile = "C:\MySpreadSheet.xls"
'strWorksheet = "WorkSheet1"
'strDB = "C:\track.accdb"
strTable = "manifests2"

Set db = CurrentDb

''The sheet takes its name from the query. This connection string depends
''on the versions of Access and Excel that you are using.
cn = "[Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;ACCDB=YES;DATABASE=" & strExcelFile & "].[OutDat$]"

''If excel file already exists, you can delete it here
If Dir(strExcelFile) <> "" Then Kill strExcelFile

''Just use an existing query.
''If a query is to be created/updated each time, you need to check
''if it exists and either create or update as appropriate.

''strSQL = "SELECT m.[Shipment ID], m.[Courier Service Level], " _
       & "m.[Other Tracking], m.[sentback]  " _
       & "FROM [" & strTable & "] As m " _
       & "WHERE m.[sentback] = 'N' And m.[Other Tracking] Is Not Null"

''db.CreateQueryDef "OutDat", strSQL

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "OutDat", strExcelFile

strSQL = "UPDATE [" & strTable & "] SET SentBack = 'Y' " _
       & "WHERE [Shipment ID] In (SELECT [Shipment ID] FROM " _
       & cn & ")"

db.Execute strSQL
```

There are some problems. For example, you have spaces in field (column) names. This is going to make life ever more difficult for you. You seem to have chosen text for `sentback` when YesNo (boolean) would be a more obvious choice. Nothing is ever equal or not equal to `null`, something `is null` or `is not null`.

Comment: Great!  One more question, is it possible NOT to write 'sentback' to the excel file but just the other 3? I guess with the update statement, i know longer need sentback in the select columns and I could remove?   Yes on the column names.  I just quickly set them up in Access using the excel file as a link, as that is how i receive the file.  So I will have to figure some sort of import mapping macro.  Thank you again.

Comment: Yes it is, just untick the box on the `Show` row under `sentback` in the query design grid. Have a look at `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink`